# Convert date to dateTtime format in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert a date column (ie. 2012-10-02) to the first day of the year with time (ie. 2012-01-01T00:00:00) in sql.

Is there a way to do so in the SELECT query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for BigQuery use below

```
select timestamp_trunc('2012-10-02', year)
```

with output

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

Note - if you column is of date type - the output will be

```
2012-01-01T00:00:00
```

and finally, you can use `datetime_trunc` instead of `timestamp_trunc` and you will get expected result - `2012-01-01T00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`YEAR()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year).

It would allow you to extract just the year, and then just as the date and time you need.